# facebook post to wall dialog is empty

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm having a weird problem with fb sdk for iphone.
It was working all fine till yesterday. I started getting an empty fb dialog when trying to post to wall. If I click Publish, it publishes fine, but the preview is not visible!
Tried uninstalling the app, also reauthorizing in fb and nothing...
Any idea?

[image: empty dialog]

Comment: I also having weird problem with the FB today. So I give them one day to resolve that problem and I will work tomorrow :)

Comment: seems like since they actually started working on their iphone apps (the new photo sharing, and the iPad version), Facebook Connect has gone down the hole as far as reliability.

Comment: Same problem here. Publish actually posts to your wall, but this webpage back from Facebook is blank. Fantastic user experience, Facebook--thanks. :P

Comment: do any one find the solution of that problem

Comment: Finally was fixed -> [FB Bug Tracker](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18760)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having same issue: please add your votes and comments to http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18760

this will help speed up the process

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have figured some things out but I don't know if that helps anybody.

There is a delegate method in FBDialog.m

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This method is called when the webview inside the facebook view is loaded.
If I load the content of the url of the request like that...

```
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:request.URL];
```

... log the source variable, copy the content inside a html document and load it with my Firefox or Safari Browser on my mac it shows up a dialog.
That means, that the there is a dialog but the webview can't show it or something like that.

The second thing I figured out, if you look further down in the method you see that there is a condition:

```
if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"fbconnect"])
```

if I log url.scheme it gives me "https" which I guess is wrong. I wonder if that shouldn't be "fbconnect" ?!
If that should be the problem I guess we can't fix the problem ourselves, since that is something Facebook need to fix.

I hope this information is at least a bit useful for you guys and I hope this bug is getting fixed soon!

Cheers,
Raphael ;)