# facebook sdk for ios feed dialog problem, not showing post although it posts

Tags: ios, facebook, ios4, dialog, fbconnect

[image for iphone with facebook feed dialog](http://i53.tinypic.com/f25uv5.jpg)

I share on facebook through the following method in the delegate who is called from all portions sharing in my app the feed dialog pops up with no content but it is actually posts on facebook wall what is wrong with my code?

```
-(void)shareOnFaceBook:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic 
{

    if(self.facebook ==nil)
    {

        self.facebook= [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"238314679531075"];

        NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  @"email", @"read_stream",@"publish_stream", nil] retain];

        [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

    }


    [self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:dic andDelegate:self];

}
```

thanks

Comment: Same problem has been [reported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522121/facebook-post-to-wall-dialog-is-empty) by others earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug reported as per the comment from Albert. but in the mean time, you can post to facebook by making an HTTP Post to the Graph API.

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"post" andParams:yourParameters andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

You will have to implement your own view controller but that should be straightforward. At least something to get you ahead while waiting for the bug to be fixed.

Comment: problem solved by facebook http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18760