# iOS Facebook connect issue with post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

I can't get a facebook connect post to work.  The odd thing is the actual post itself works when the publish button is clicked.  But for some reason the actual post dialog doesn't have any content between the "Post to wall" and the buttons on the bottom.  I've tried running it with the demo app too, same result.  This worked last week.  Anyone come across this?  Here's my dialog code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:content.siteUrl, @"link", nil];
[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Nevermind, just saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522121/facebook-post-to-wall-dialog-is-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was on facebook's side.  It's back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"post" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```